# Doing exponential operation using only addition in Java

Tags: java, exponential

I'm having trouble making this program. Is it possible to write a program by getting the exponential value without using `*, ^, Math.pow`? Example I have base of 2 and the exponent is 3.

> Q1. what operation should I used to help the addition to come up with the correct result?
>
> Q2. addition is enough?

Comment: If the base will be `2` then you could, for example, use a bit shift. Just shift it to the left the number of times of your exponent less one.

Comment: `^` means exclusive OR in Java, it doesn't have anything to do with exponentiation.

Comment: but i'm new in java sir, i don't know how to use this bit shift. is there any other way like looping it?

Comment: You could implement multiplication with a loop and addition. Then you could implement exponentiation with a loop and your multiplication method.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch we cannot use this operation *, ^, Math.pow. only addition but i think division is fine tho

Comment: @HilverBomb Read my comment again.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch sorry i didnt get it so do you mean i have to create a multiplication method?

Comment: @HilverBomb That would be the route I would pursue. You could implement multiplication with a nested loop, but I would start by creating a multiplication method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to only use addition to do exponentiation. Remember that multiplication is the repetition of addition many times, and that exponentiation is the repetition of multiplication many times.

For example, you could write the following function that will exponentiate a number:

```
double exp(long base, long exponent) {

    //when the exponent is zero
    if (exponent == 0) return 1.0;

    long result = base;
    long exponent_abs = Math.abs(exponent);

    //repeating multiplication many times to achieve exponentiation
    for (int i = 2 ; i <= exponent_abs ; ++i) {

        result = multiply(result, base);
    }

     //if the exponent is positive, return result you found.
     if (exponent > 0) return result;
     //if it is negative, return a fraction.
     return 1/((double)result);
  }

//repeating addition many times to achieve multiplication.
long multiply(long number1, long number2){
    long result = number1;

    for (int i = 1; i < number2; ++i){
        result += number1;
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Note that the function returns a double value, since if your exponent is negative, the result cannot be expressed with an integral type.

Comment: You can't use `!exponent` in Java. You'd need `exponent == 0`.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas can you help me out a little here how am i going to call it in my main i want to print it so i can see what happen? and what is math.abs?

Comment: Math.abs finds the absolute value of a number.  You need it if the value of the exponent is negative.

Comment: @HilverBomb. Don't forget to accept the answer that best answered your question.

Comment: i made it like this public static double pow and i call it in my main
System.out.println("" +pow(base, exp));
i input 2 as base and 3 as exponent it gives me the result of 2.0

Comment: Don't use it still. I need to fix some things.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exponential{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Base: ");
  int base = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Exponent: ");
  int exponent = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("" + pow(base, exponent));

    }
} 
i made it like this. but when i input 2 as base and 3 as exponent it gives me the base(2.0).

Comment: I am coming with a fix in the next 3 minutes.

Comment: @HilverBomb, you can use it now.

Comment: i think multiply method is not that accurate 2,3 it gives me 4

Comment: multiply(2,3) gives 6 in my machine.

Comment: it should be 8 2 to the power of 3, i been implementing other things to the code it gives me a headache :)

Comment: exp(2, 3) gives 8 in my machine and multiply(2,3) gives 6 in my machine. Give me an email to send you the code.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas this is the problem for (int i = 2 ; i <= exponent_abs ; ++i) {

        result = multiply(result, base);
    } it's start with 2 can you please change it to 1. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use those functions of the language?
Anyway:

```
public int pow (final int base, final int exponent) {
  int result = base;
  for (int i = 1; i < exponent; i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < base; j++)
         result += base;
  return result;
}
```

This obviously only works for integers (or longs really), if you have a floating value as exponent I dont think you can avoid ^ or `Math.pow`

Note that I have not tested this but should work along the line of this, I might have messed up somewhere.

You should also note thate x^0=1, so add an extra check there. And this only works with signed ints, as this algorithm is not made for negatives